# Bring element to front using CSS

Tags: html, css, z-index, jsfiddle

I can't figure out how to bring images to front using `CSS`. I've already tried setting z-index to 1000 and position to relative, but it still fails.

Here's example-

```css
#header {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/420x160) center top no-repeat;
}
#header-inner {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/150/200) right top no-repeat;
}
.logo-class {
    height: 128px;
}
.content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.td-main {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 80px 10px 80px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #A02422;
    background: #ABABAB;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header-inner">
            <table class="content">
                <col width="400px" />
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table class="content">
                            <col width="400px" />
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="logo-class"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="menu"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table class="content">
                            <col width="120px" />
                            <col width="160px" />
                            <col width="120px" />
                            <tr>
                                <td class="td-main">text</td>
                                <td class="td-main">text</td>
                                <td class="td-main">text</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- header-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- header -->
</body>
```

Comment: Bring what to front ? Also the **<col>** is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/col).

Comment: Bring the images to front.

Comment: Why are you using nested tables to make a menu?

Comment: I had problems with the menu in IE8 and nested tables fixed it.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l55hSbBUdmQ) is extremely helpful to understand how it works.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Add `z-index:-1` and `position:relative` to .content

```css
#header {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/420x160) center top no-repeat;
}
#header-inner {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/150/200) right top no-repeat;
}
.logo-class {
    height: 128px;
}
.content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    z-index: -1;
    position:relative;
}
.td-main {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 80px 10px 80px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #A02422;
    background: #ABABAB;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header-inner">
            <table class="content">
                <col width="400px" />
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table class="content">
                            <col width="400px" />
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="logo-class"></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="menu"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table class="content">
                            <col width="120px" />
                            <col width="160px" />
                            <col width="120px" />
                            <tr>
                                <td class="td-main">text</td>
                                <td class="td-main">text</td>
                                <td class="td-main">text</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- header-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- header -->
</body>
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. Can you please explain why does this work?

Comment: @Germstorm `Z-index` controls how images or divs stack over each other. Div/image with higher z-index value takes front place and lower would stay behind.

Comment: I don't really remember the circumstances of my question clearly, but my problem was, that I understood what `z-index` does, but still it did not work. What I have learned from this answer is, that with `z-index` you have to take into consideration the parent hierarchy as well.

Comment: @Germstorm Recent answer from Soon Khai is the correct explanation: z-index has no effect if element isn't positioned

Comment: And use z-index: +1 to bring something to front :D

Comment: @SpiderMan Where did you come up with `+1`? That's not valid.

Answer (score 55):

Note: z-index [only works on positioned elements](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) (`position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`). Use one of those.

Comment: they said in the question that they set the position to relative

Answer (score 9):

In my case i had to move the html code of the element i wanted at the front at the end of the html file, because if one element has z-index and the other doesn't have z index it doesn't work.

Comment: The 2 parts of your answer aren't related (at least with no other details). First part is a solution because _al other properties equal_ latter element in HTML code  is displayed above previous ones. Second part is some comment about how z-index has some effect.

Comment: good point about all elements must have z-index for it to work. thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Another Note: z-index must be considered when looking at children objects relative to other objects.

For example

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="branch_1">
        <div class="branch_1__child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="branch_2">
        <div class="branch_2__child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you gave `branch_1__child` a z-index of `99` and you gave `branch_2__child` a z-index of 1, but you also gave your `branch_2` a z-index of `10` and your `branch_1` a z-index of `1`, your `branch_1__child` still will not show up in front of your `branch_2__child`

Anyways, what I'm trying to say is; if a parent of an element you'd like to be placed in front has a lower z-index than its relative, that element will not be placed higher.

The z-index is relative to its containers.  A z-index placed on a container farther up in the hierarchy basically starts a new "layer"

Incep[inception]tion

Here's a fiddle to play around:

https://jsfiddle.net/orkLx6o8/