# How to bring an element to the front using css?

Tags: css, wordpress

Hello I am working on a WordPress site, and I am trying to place a countdown shortcode just on my header.

What I have tried to do is to float this shortcode using CSS but the issue is it goes under my navigation header

This what I was applying

```
.mycodes{
   position:absolute;
   top : 0%;
   right:42.5%;
padding-bottom : 10px;

  }
```

I also applied this

```
z-index: -1;
```

After searching online, but the div and shortcode disappears

And the short code

```
[notdevice]<div class="mycodes">[flipclock]</div>[/notdevice]
```

This is the [website](http://www.femessence.net/mine-2/) so you will see what am talking about

I want it to show on the header instead of showing behind it

Someone please help

Comment: try `z-index: 9999;` and `position:relative`

Comment: ok tanks let me do dat

Comment: or try `z-index: -1;` and `position:relative`

Comment: Note: z-index [only works on positioned elements](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed). Use one of those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bring element to front using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782078/bring-element-to-front-using-css)

Answer (score 5):

```
z-index: -1;
```

will put your element behind all other elements (as well as the background from `<body>`)

the reason to use `z-index` is to bring elements in front of other elements or vice versa.

the inherit value of `z-index` is `auto`. if nothing else on your page is z-indexed you could try to put `z-index` on 2. if this won't show your element try to higher the value until your element is shown.

your navigation btw has following css rules:

```
.include-nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9998!important;
}
```

so to put something ABOVE this you have to higher the `z-index` to at least 9999.

for further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: I think this is very simple typo question so instead of giving answer there can be duplicate questions as well as this question needed to be deleted. :-)

Comment: well, if someone tries to bring an element in front of another with `z-index: -1;` it looks like he doesn't really understand z-index, so i tried to explain :)

Comment: how is it a typo question, all am trying to do is to float a div on my navigation bar

Comment: @RohanKhude typo !!!= type of. Also Tee, floating in CSS means something totally else than the layering order of elements.