# CSS - Bring check box to front

Tags: html, css

I found a similar question to mine here but the accepted answer did not fix my issue.

> [Bring element to front using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782078/bring-element-to-front-using-css)

I have made custom check boxes and I am trying to bring them to the front. Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Title">
            <img src="" alt="WifiFinder.img" id="WifiFinderImg">
            <input type="button" class="Headerbuttons" id="back" value="Actually, I already have an account!" onclick="document.location='searchpage.html';"/>
        </div>
        <div id="AccountRegistration">
            <h2>Username</h2>
            <input class="userinfo" type="text" value="Username Here"/>
            <h2>Email Address</h2>
            <input class="userinfo" type="email" value="Email Address"/>
            <h2>Date of Birth</h2>
            <input class="userinfo" type="date" value="DD/MM/YYYY"/>
            <h2>Password</h2>
            <input class="userinfo" type="password" value="Password"/>
            <h2>Retype Password</h2>
            <input class="userinfo" type="password" value="Password"/>
            <label class="container">I have Read and Accept the Terms and Conditions
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
              <label class="container">I have Read and Accept the Privacy Statement
                   <input type="checkbox">
                   <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
              <input class="buttons" type="button" value="Create Account" onclick="alert('Hello World');"/>
        </div>
    </body>
```

The CSS for this is as follows:

```
:root{
    --main-color: #0052CC;
    --secondary-color: #172B4D;
    --tertiary-color: #FFFFFF;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--tertiary-color);
    margin: 0%;
}

#Title {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    margin: 0%;
}

#WifiFinderImg{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
}

/*The main content on the account registration page*/
#AccountRegistration{
    font-size: x-large;
    position: absolute;
    height: 70%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    bottom: 0%;
    color: var(--main-color);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: var(--secondary-color) 1px solid;
}

/*Class to style user input feilds for account creation*/
.userinfo{
    font-size: large;
    width: 40%;
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px var(--main-color) solid;
    text-align: center;
    color: lightgrey;
}

/*Customize the label*/
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: x-large;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }

  /*Hide the browser's default checkbox*/
.container input {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  /*Create a custom checkbox*/
.checkmark {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 35%;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: lightgray;
  }

  /*On mouse-over, add a light grey background color*/
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: lightslategrey;
  }

  /*When the checkbox is checked, add a main colour background*/
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
  }

  /*Create the checkmark*/
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

  /*Show the checkmark when checked*/
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
  }

/*Style the checkmark*/
.container .checkmark:after {
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid var(--tertiary-color);
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

/*Class to style all content buttons*/
.buttons{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -10%;
    margin-top: -5%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    top: 150%;
    left: 5%;
    font-size: x-large;
    width: 20%;
    height: 10%;
    border: 1px var(--main-color) solid;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--tertiary-color);
}

/*Hover action for content buttons*/
.buttons:hover{
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    border-color: var(--secondary-color);
}

/*Buttons in the header*/
.Headerbuttons{
    width: 15%;
    height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    right: 2%;
    border: 1px var(--tertiary-color) solid;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--tertiary-color);
}

/*Hover actions for buttons in the header*/
.Headerbuttons:hover{
    background-color: var(--tertiary-color);
    border-color: var(--tertiary-color);
    color: var(--main-color);
}
```

It seems to work when I change the position of the checkbox from relative to absolute, but then the problem is that they are on different parts of the page for different sized screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add**  `display: inline-block;`

**Here is the working Snippet**

```css
:root {
 --main-color: #0052CC;
 --secondary-color: #172B4D;
 --tertiary-color: #FFFFFF;
}
body {
 background-color: var(--tertiary-color);
 margin: 0%;
}
#Title {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 30%;
 background-color: var(--main-color);
 margin: 0%;
}
#WifiFinderImg {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 50%;
 left: 0%;
 bottom: 0%;
 margin: 0%;
}
/*The main content on the account registration page*/
#AccountRegistration {
 font-size: x-large;
 position: absolute;
 height: 70%;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 bottom: 0%;
 color: var(--main-color);
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 border: var(--secondary-color) 1px solid;
}
/*Class to style user input feilds for account creation*/
.userinfo {
 font-size: large;
 width: 40%;
 border: 0px;
 border-bottom: 1px var(--main-color) solid;
 text-align: center;
 color: lightgrey;
}
/*Customize the label*/
.container {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 35px;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: x-large;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}
/*Hide the browser's default checkbox*/
.container input {
 position: relative;
 opacity: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
/*Create a custom checkbox*/
.checkmark {
 position: relative;
 top: 4px;
 left: 0;
 height: 25px;
 width: 25px;
 background-color: lightgray;
 display: inline-block; /* Added */
}
/*On mouse-over, add a light grey background color*/
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
 background-color: lightslategrey;
}
/*When the checkbox is checked, add a main colour background*/
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
 background-color: var(--main-color);
}
/*Create the checkmark*/
.checkmark:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
}
/*Show the checkmark when checked*/
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
 display: block;
}
/*Style the checkmark*/
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid var(--tertiary-color);
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
/*Class to style all content buttons*/
.buttons {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -10%;
  margin-top: -5%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  top: 150%;
  left: 5%;
  font-size: x-large;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px var(--main-color) solid;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  color: var(--tertiary-color);
}
/*Hover action for content buttons*/
.buttons:hover {
 background-color: var(--secondary-color);
 border-color: var(--secondary-color);
}
/*Buttons in the header*/
.Headerbuttons {
  width: 15%;
  height: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 2%;
  border: 1px var(--tertiary-color) solid;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  color: var(--tertiary-color);
}
/*Hover actions for buttons in the header*/
.Headerbuttons:hover {
  background-color: var(--tertiary-color);
  border-color: var(--tertiary-color);
  color: var(--main-color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Title"> <img src="" alt="WifiFinder.img" id="WifiFinderImg">
    <input type="button" class="Headerbuttons" id="back" value="Actually, I already have an account!" onclick="document.location='searchpage.html';"/>
</div>
<div id="AccountRegistration">
    <h2>Username</h2>
    <input class="userinfo" type="text" value="Username Here"/>
    <h2>Email Address</h2>
    <input class="userinfo" type="email" value="Email Address"/>
    <h2>Date of Birth</h2>
    <input class="userinfo" type="date" value="DD/MM/YYYY"/>
    <h2>Password</h2>
    <input class="userinfo" type="password" value="Password"/>
    <h2>Retype Password</h2>
    <input class="userinfo" type="password" value="Password"/>
    <label class="container">I have Read and Accept the Terms and Conditions
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </label>
    <label class="container">I have Read and Accept the Privacy Statement
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </label>
    <input class="buttons" type="button" value="Create Account" onclick="alert('Hello World');"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I change that, it reveals the original check boxes. I am hiding them as I create a custom one below that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed that you've used position relative and absolute amateur-ly (throughout the code).

Since you've mentioned that the checkboxes are used at multiple places, you need to a way to apply different styles. For that, I will add another class here.

Replace this:

```
<span class="checkmark"></span>
```

and this

```
.checkmark {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 35%;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: lightgray;
  }
```

With this:

```
<span class="checkmark customCheckmark"></span>
```

and this

```
.checkmark {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 35%;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: lightgray;
  }
  .checkmark.customCheckmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: lightgray;
  }
```

CSS-Tricks might be able to explain this in more depth.
https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Note: As a general rule of thumb, try not to use too many position relatives and absolutes, they mess up your CSS in most cases. If you're a beginner in CSS, try using Flexbox, it's much easier to learn and implement than conventional CSS.

Comment: When I change that to absolute, it messes with the position of the custom checkbox on different screens with different resolutions. I am just looking for a way to bring the element to the front.

Comment: If you've used these checkboxes in multiple pages, try to use different classes. Let me edit my answer to include that case.